# How do we get from here the desired result?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let $\textbf{$\gamma$} (t)$ be a regular plane curve and let $\lambda$ be a constant. The parallel curve $\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda}$ of $\textbf{$\gamma$}$ is defined by $\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda}(t) = \textbf{$\gamma$} (t) + \lambda \textbf{n}_s(t)$.

Show that, if $\lambda \kappa_s(t) \neq 1$ for all values of $t$, then $\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda}$ is a regular curve and that its signed curvature is $\frac{\kappa_s}{|1 − \lambda \kappa_s|}$.

$$$$

I have shown that if $\lambda \kappa_s(t) \neq 1$ for all values of $t$, then $\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda}$ is a regular curve.

I am facing some difficulties at showing that the signed curvature is $\frac{\kappa_s}{|1 − \lambda \kappa_s|}$.

I have done the following for this part:

The signed curvature $\kappa_s^{\lambda}$ is equal to $$\kappa_s^{\lambda}=\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda ''}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda}$$

$\textbf{n}_s$ is the signed unit perpendicular vector to $\textbf{$\gamma$}$. 
Since $\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda}$ is parallel to $\textbf{$\gamma$}$ and $\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda}$ is the signed unit perpendicular vector to $\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda}$, we have that $\textbf{n}_s | | \textbf{n}_s^{\lambda}$, i.e., $ \textbf{n}_s^{\lambda}=a\textbf{n}_s$.

We have that $\textbf{t}=\frac{\textbf{$\gamma$}'(t)}{\|\textbf{$\gamma$} '(t)\|}=\frac{\textbf{$\gamma$}'(t)}{s'(t)} \Rightarrow \textbf{$\gamma$}'(t)=s'(t)\textbf{t}$.

So, we have $$\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda '}(t) = \dot s\mathbf t (1- \lambda \kappa_s )  \Rightarrow \textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda '}(t) = \dot s\mathbf t - \lambda \kappa_s \dot s\mathbf t  \Rightarrow \textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda '}(t) = \dot s\mathbf t + \lambda \textbf{n}_s'$$

Differentiating the relation $$\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda '}(t) = \dot s\mathbf t + \lambda \textbf{n}_s'$$ we get $$\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda ''}(t) = \ddot s\mathbf t +\dot s\mathbf {\dot t} + \lambda \textbf{n}_s''$$

Then we have $$\kappa_s^{\lambda}=\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda ''}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} \Rightarrow \kappa_s^{\lambda}=\left (\ddot s\mathbf t +\dot s\mathbf {\dot t} + \lambda \textbf{n}_s''\right ) a\textbf{n}_s$$

Is this correct so far? How do we get from here the desired result?

Comment: \begin{equation}
\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda '}(t) = \dot s\mathbf t - \lambda \kappa_s \dot s\mathbf t  \Rightarrow \textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda '}(t) = \dot s\mathbf t + \lambda \textbf{n}_s'
\end{equation}

This implies that

\begin{equation}
\kappa_s \dot s\mathbf t = -\textbf{n}_s'
\end{equation}

Is that correct?

Comment: At an other exercise I had shown that for a regular unit-speed curve it stands that $$\textbf{n}_s'=-k_s\textbf{$\gamma$}'$$ So, in general for a regular curve, not necessarily unit-speed, it stands that $$\textbf{n}_s'=-\kappa_s \dot s\mathbf t $$ @JacobCheverie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the definition of the parallel curve $\gamma^{\lambda}$ and take it's derivative with respect to time. Then,

\begin{align}
\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda'}(t) &= \textbf{$\gamma'$} (t) + \lambda \textbf{n}_s'(t) \\
\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda'}(t) &= \dot s(t)\textbf{t} - \lambda \kappa_s \dot s(t)\textbf{t} \\
\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda'}(t) &= \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\dot s(t)\textbf{t} \\
\dot s^{\lambda}(t)\textbf{t}^{\lambda} &= \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\dot s(t)\textbf{t}
\end{align}

Since $\textbf{t}^{\lambda} \parallel \textbf{t}$, 
\begin{equation}
\dot s^{\lambda}(t) = \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\dot s(t) \\
\frac {ds^{\lambda}(t)}{dt} = \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\frac {ds(t)}{dt}
\end{equation}

Arc length for the parallel curve has to be distinguished from arc length for the original curve. Same with unit tangent. Then,

\begin{align}
\textbf{t} &= \frac{\textbf{$\gamma$}'(t)}{s'(t)} \\
\textbf{t}^{\lambda} &= \frac{\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda'}(t)}{s^{\lambda'}(t)} = a \textbf{t} \\
\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} &= a\textbf{n}_s
\end{align}

Then the signed curvature $\kappa_s^{\lambda}$ is

\begin{align}
\kappa_s^{\lambda}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda}=\frac{d\textbf{t}^{\lambda}}{ds^{\lambda}(t)} = \dfrac {\frac {d\textbf{t}^{\lambda}}{dt}}{\frac {ds^{\lambda}(t)}{dt}}
\end{align}

By substitution,

\begin{align}
\kappa_s^{\lambda}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} &= \dfrac {a\frac {d\textbf{t}}{dt}}{\left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\frac {ds(t)}{dt}} \\
\kappa_s^{\lambda}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} &= a \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s \right)^{-1} \frac {d\textbf{t}} {ds(t)}
\end{align}

By the definition of signed curvature, $\kappa_s \textbf{n}_s = \frac {d\textbf{t}} {ds(t)}$, so by substitution

\begin{align}
\kappa_s^{\lambda}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} &= a \kappa_s \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s \right)^{-1} \textbf{n}_s
\end{align}

Since $\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} = a\textbf{n}_s$, or $\frac{1}{a}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} = \textbf{n}_s$,

\begin{align}
\kappa_s^{\lambda}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} &= \frac {a}{a} \kappa_s \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s \right)^{-1} \textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} \\
\kappa_s^{\lambda}\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} &= \kappa_s \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s \right)^{-1} \textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} 
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
\kappa_s^{\lambda} = \dfrac{\kappa_s} {\left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s \right)}
\end{equation}

I'm not sure about the absolute value...

Comment: To get the desired result we want that $$a=\frac{1}{(1-\lambda \kappa_s)^2}$$ or not? Can we calculate it somehow?

Comment: Can you just assume that it's true? Or force it to be? $a$ is simply a scaling factor of the unit normal vector $\textbf{n}_s$ if I'm not mistaken. And since you showed that $\lambda \kappa_s \neq 1$ for all values of $t$, I would think that maybe you could choose that to be $a$.

Comment: @MaryStar I have modified my answer to get what you are looking for. You have to keep in mind that the arc length on $\gamma ^{\lambda}$ must be treated as a separate quantity, namely $s^{\lambda}(t)$.

Comment: Ok... Why does it stand that $$\textbf{t}^{\lambda} = \frac{\textbf{$\gamma$}^{\lambda'}(t)}{s^{\lambda'}(t)} = a \textbf{t}$$ ?

Comment: Definition of unit tangent for $\gamma^{\lambda}$ and since $\mathbf{t} \parallel \mathbf{t}^{\lambda}$

Comment: But before you said: "$$\dot s^{\lambda}(t)\textbf{t}^{\lambda} = \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\dot s(t)\textbf{t}
$$

Since $\textbf{t}^{\lambda} \parallel \textbf{t}$, 
$$\dot s^{\lambda}(t) = \left(1 - \lambda \kappa_s\right)\dot s(t)$$" Does this mean that $\textbf{t}^{\lambda}=\textbf{t}$ ?

Comment: Aren't $\textbf{t}$ and $\textbf{t}^{\lambda}$ unit vectors? That would imply $a=1$.

Comment: So is it also $$\textbf{n}_s^{\lambda} = \textbf{n}_s$$ ?

Comment: It is also a unit vector, or not?

Comment: Since $\textbf{t}^{\lambda} \parallel \textbf{t}$ and since $\textbf{t}$ and $\textbf{t}^{\lambda}$ are unit vectors, do we not conclude that $\textbf{t}^{\lambda}=\pm \textbf{t}$ and not just $\textbf{t}^{\lambda}=\textbf{t}$ ?